# Draw texture directly onto screen/client coordinates

Tags: directx

I am using orthogonal projection if it matters, and I can draw a texture onto the world using world coordinates. For HUD objects it works fine at first, but once I have a camera and it moves, all my HUD textures moves along with the world, hence going out of the camera's view sooner or later.

In order to draw on the HUD, they must be drawn using client coordinates (either top left or center as (0,0)). Any idea on how to do that? I am quite new to this so I would appreciate more detailed help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well if you set an identity view and projection matrix then all coordinates will simply pass through to the screen.  Post projection and w divide -1,-1 is the bottom left and 1, 1 is the top right with 0,0 being the center.

Now if you wanted to be able to pass in screen coordinates you would need to set up a world matrix such that 0, 0, z comes out as -1, 1, z and 1024,768, z (for example) comes out as 1, -1, z, 1 (z is used to give you a specific depth and can be used to layer HUD elements over each other). A good understanding of linear algebra helps a lot here.

Essentially if you were to write it you'd do the following

```
xout = (x / (width * 0.5f)) - 1.0f;
yout = -((y / (height * 0.5f)) - 1.0f);
zout = z;
wout = 1.0f;
```

So if you remember your matrices you get something like this.

```
m00, m01, m02, m03,
m10, m11, m12, m13,
m20, m21, m22, m23,
m30, m31, m32, m33,
```

Matrix expansion is such that the input x coordinate will always be transformed by the first column as follows:

```
xout = m00 * x + m10 * y + m20 * z + m30 * w;
```

First thing to remember is that a coordinate triple passed into directX (x,y,z) gets expanded to the quadruple (x,y,z,1).

This way we can easily see that if m10 and m20 are 0 then effectively we multiply x by some value and then we add what ever value is in m30 afterwards.

So going back to our original description of how to calculate xout we can see that if we set m00 to "1.0f / (width * 0.5f)" and m30 to -1.0f then we will calculate what we are after.  Therefore assuming:

```
xscale = 1.0f / (width * 0.5f);
yscale = -1.0f / (height * 0.5f);
zscale = 1.0f;
xtrans = -1.0f;
ytrans = 1.0f;
ztrans = 0.0f;
```

Then we can define out world matrix as follows:

```
xscale,      0,      0,      0
     0, yscale,      0,      0
     0,      0, zscale,      0
xtrans, ytrans, ztrans,      1
```

Set that matrix as your world matrix (Remember to set view and projection to identity) and you can now input your coordinates using screen coordinates.

Comment: Thanks! It works great when I set View to identity. Didn't work fine when Projection was identity as well. Just wondering, now that I have the center as (0, 0), is it also possible for me to shift the origin to top left somehow?

Comment: @CyberMew:  The rest of my post explains how to select a world matrix that that will work for this.  Also if you aren't setting your projection matrix to identity then you are going to get problems as the projection matrix will end up skewing the resulting image.